# Is it possible to check if there are any instances of a class in memory with Xcode lldb console?

Tags: xcode

Can Xcode's lldb console be used to query the memory graph?  Of course, we can use the memory graph debugger or instruments to inspect the memory graph, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to answer the question "How many instances of MyClass are in memory?" without firing up those tools